# Char to String conversion Ada

Tags: type-conversion, ada

I am trying to iterate through chars and print them using `Put_Line()` function but it takes String parameters, not chars. Is it possible to convert char to String like I can do it with Integer using `'Image()`? My code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is

begin
  for I in 'A' .. 'Z' loop
    Put_Line(I);
  end loop;
end Main;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is not only Character conversion but you need also to inform compiler what kind of Character you will use, and yes, you can use Image attribute to get String representation of a char.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is

begin
   for I in Character range 'A' .. 'Z' loop
      Put_Line(I'Image);
   end loop;
end Main;
```

This code will work.

Comment: Thanks for this - I wasn’t aware of the new `X’Image`, only the GNAT `’Img`.

Comment: `X'Image ` is a new GNAT extension that probably anticipates Ada 2020. The problem is that, like `X'Img` or the standard `Character'Image` it prints the character in quotes (i.e. `'A'`). A simple way to create a string from a character is concatenate the character to an empty string (i.e. `Put_line("" & I);`.

Comment: Using GNATMAKE GPL 2015 (20150428-49) compilation fails with "prefix of "Image" attribute must be a type". If the code compiles with a newer compiler will someone please clarify at what point this became a language feature.